# Why are the elements for ids for my HTML elements not getting processed properly by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
console.log("var numbers = [");
for (let i = numberOfInputs; i < dlArray.length + numberOfInputs; i++) {
  footer += dlArray[i - numberOfInputs].replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
  console.log(dlArray[i - numberOfInputs].replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""));
  footer += ",";
  console.log(",");
}
console.log("];");
footer += "];";
footer += "initialize(numbers);";
```

The output of the statement above is the following

```
var numbers = [
word_match.js:183 3
word_match.js:185 ,
word_match.js:183 1
word_match.js:185 ,
word_match.js:183 4
word_match.js:185 ,
word_match.js:183 2
word_match.js:185 ,
word_match.js:187 ];
word_match.js:203
```

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev, number) {
  //        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ""+number);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Number", number);
}

function drop(ev, number) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  //            var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");
  //        alert("id " + id);

  //        var num = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var num = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Number");

  if (number == num) {
    document
      .getElementById("row" + number)
      .style.setProperty("background", "green");
    document.getElementById("row" + number).style.setProperty("color", "white");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    document.getElementById(data).style.setProperty("background", "green");
    document.getElementById(data).style.setProperty("font-style", "italic");
    document
      .getElementById(data)
      .style.setProperty("border", "0px solid green");
    document
      .getElementById(data)
      .style.setProperty("border-right", "1px solid green");
    //                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById("drag"+num));
  }
}

var correctCards = 0;
var totalCount;
var copyNumbers;

function initialize(numbers) {
  copyNumbers = numbers;
  correctCards = 0;
  totalCount = numbers.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    $("#s" + (i + 1))
      .data("number", numbers[i])
      .draggable({
        containment: "#boxstyle",
        cursor: "move",
        revert: true
      });
  }

  // Create the slots
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    $("#t" + (i + 1))
      .data("number", i + 1)
      .droppable({
        hoverClass: "hovered",
        drop: handDrop
      });
  }
}

function handDrop(event, ui) {
  var sourceNumber = $(this).data("number");
  var targetNumber = ui.draggable.data("number");

  if (sourceNumber == targetNumber) {
    ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this), my: "center", at: "center" });
    ui.draggable.draggable("disable");
    $(this).droppable("disable");
    ui.draggable.draggable("option", "revert", false);

    //    $('#d' + targetNumber).css("background", "goldenrod");
    //    $('#d' + targetNumber).css("color", "white");
    //    $('#t' + targetNumber).css("background", "goldenrod");
    $("#d" + targetNumber).css("border-top", "1px solid");
    $("#d" + targetNumber).css("border-bottom", "1px solid");
    $("#d" + targetNumber).css("border-color", "white");
    $("#d" + targetNumber).css("background", "#3F5E17");
    $("#d" + targetNumber).css("color", "white");
    $("#t" + targetNumber).css("background", "#3F5E17");

    document.getElementById("resetButton").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("resetButton").style.visibility = "visible";

    //    $('#t' + targetNumber).css("background", "goldenrod");
    $("#t" + targetNumber).css("color", "white");

    for (var i = 0; i < copyNumbers.length; i++) {
      if (copyNumbers[i] == sourceNumber) break;
    }

    speak($("#s" + (i + 1)).text() + ". " + $("#d" + targetNumber).text());
    // jAlert('Done', "Test");

    correctCards++;
  }

  if (correctCards == totalCount) {
    jAlert("You did it!", "Congratulations");
    document.getElementById("resetButton").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

Actual

```
<div id="boxstyle">
  <h3 id="title">title</h3>
  <center>
    <div class="source">
      <div id="s1" class="draggyBox-small ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        k3
      </div>
      <div id="s2" class="draggyBox-small ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        k1
      </div>
      <div id="s3" class="draggyBox-small ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        k4
      </div>
      <div id="s4" class="draggyBox-small ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        k2
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
  <table id="tablestyle">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="row1">
          <div id="t1" class="ltarget ui-droppable"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d1">
          d3
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="row2">
          <div id="t2" class="ltarget ui-droppable"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d2">
          d1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="row3">
          <div id="t3" class="ltarget ui-droppable"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d3">
          d4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="row4">
          <div id="t4" class="ltarget ui-droppable"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d4">
          d2
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Expected

```
<div id="boxstyle">
  <h3 id="title">title</h3>
  <center>
    <div class="source">
      <div id="s1" class="draggyBox-small ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        k3
      </div>
      <div id="s2" class="draggyBox-small ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        k1
      </div>
      <div id="s3" class="draggyBox-small ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        k4
      </div>
      <div id="s4" class="draggyBox-small ui-draggable" style="position: relative;">
        k2
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
  <table id="tablestyle">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="row1">
          <div id="t1" class="ltarget ui-droppable"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d3">
          d3
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="row2">
          <div id="t1" class="ltarget ui-droppable"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d1">
          d1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="row3">
          <div id="t4" class="ltarget ui-droppable"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d4">
          d4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="row4">
          <div id="t2" class="ltarget ui-droppable"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="d2">
          d2
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Visually this does not come out as expected. I would expect the descriptions and keys to match up side by side. However they are misplaced. Please see the screen shot below

[image]

How can I fix the init method? For example, when I drag key element with the id s2 over the row element with the id t2 the element should be dropped into place. The sourceNumber and targetNumber do not match up properly.

Comment: Please click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: What does "they are misplaced" mean specifically?

Comment: Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 110459. @mplungjan

Comment: [mcve] does not mean we want to see ALL your code, just the minimum to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the way that the handDrop method was being called

```
function initialize(numbers) {
  copyNumbers = numbers;
  correctCards = 0;
  totalCount = numbers.length;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    console.log("'#s' + (i + 1) is matched with "+numbers[i])
    $('#s' + (i + 1)).data('number', numbers[i]).draggable( {
      containment: '#boxstyle',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }

  // Create the slots
    for ( var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
    console.log("'#t' + (i + 1) is matched with "+numbers[i])
    $('#t' + (i + 1)).data('number', numbers[i]).droppable( {
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handDrop
    } );
  }
}
```

The targets t_i were not matching with the s_i elements. By changing

```
$("#t" + (i + 1))
      .data("number", i + 1)
```

to

```
$("#t" + (i + 1))
      .data("number", numbers[i])
```

I was able to fix the problem.